# Check specific sequence of alphanumeric string in sas

Tags: sas

I have data with an ID field that is structured like this:

XX00000X

7 characters total, with the first 2 and last letters only, and numbers in between.

How can I check that the ID is structured specifically and exactly like this?

I'm not sure of how to approach checking this - one possibility was the CATs function but not sure how to apply that.

Comment: What is the question?  That type of data would need to be put into a character varaible.

Comment: How do you check that the ID has two letters, 5 numbers, and one letter at the end with specifically 8 characters?  But not any sequence, specifically: XX00000X

Comment: What have you tried? Use SUBSTR or CHAR along with ANYALPHA/ANYDIGIT to check for the correct values? PRX is ideal but if you don't know regular expressions it's a pain. I would probably recommend CHAR() and a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of functions to check this, including:
CHAR()
ANYDIGIT()
ANYALPHA()

```
data have;
input x $10.;
cards;
AB0000X
AO000BF
1234556
ABCDEFG
AB0123Y
AB
ABCDEFGHI
;
run;

data check;
set have;

flag=0;
if lengthn(x) ne 7 then flag=1;
length letter $1;

if flag=0 then do i=1 to 7;
letter = char(x, i);
if ( i in (1,2, 7) and anyalpha(letter) ne 1  )
    or i in (3:6) and anydigit(letter) ne 1  then do; 
        flag=1; 
        leave;
end;

end;

run;
```

Regular expressions are obviously more succinct and likely a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach by regular expression. [A-Z]{2} mathc first two letters, [0-9]{4} match four digits in the middle, [A-Z] match last letter, i ignore case.

```
data want;
   set have;
   flag=prxmatch("m/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]/i",x);
run;
```